# Sorting in SSRS Matrix report.I want to sort the product sold based on the lasted date

Tags: sorting, matrix, reporting-services

My data set:

```
Product |  07/12|  07/11|  07/10|  07/09
--------+-------+-------+-------+-------
Apple   |     10|      3|      2|      5
Orange  |      3|      4|      3|      1
Grapes  |      6|      2|      5|      0
Tomato  |      4|      6|      2|      1
```

When I apply sort the Matrix table should be sorted based the 07/12 column values.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using column groups, go to the properties of the group and use sort section to set sorting as per needed.

And if your data is not in the correct format (in this case in date format), you can convert data using expressions (i.e. cDate(yourDateField)) and then can apply sorting based on expression result.

**Edit:**

You can access column grouping from:

[image]

And you can set sorting from:

[image]

*And if you are looking to sort row based on the column heading, you can apply sorting on row grouping using the custom expression. i.e. only sort where date value is 7/12 etc.*